# Gradle + bintray: Specifying Dependencies of dependencies correctly

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies

I have the following scenario:

I want to use a project of mine (hosted on [bintray.com](http://bintray.com/)) in another project of mine.

I set up a maven repository, uploaded artifacts and pom files and then was able to utilize the jar file(s) uploaded to the bintray maven repo just fine, with the following `build.gradle` file:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'randers.test.usageTest.UsageTest'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/randers00/NotEnoughVocab' }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'randers.notenoughvocab.core', name: 'notenoughvocab-core', version: '0.0.1', ext: 'jar')
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": mainClassName
    }
}
```

This build file successfully equips the project with my core library and even makes sources, etc. available in the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA I use)

The problem is: The core itself uses libraries, which are not gotten by gradle.

This is the pom file that is on bintray:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>randers.notenoughvocab.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>notenoughvocab-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>GNU General Public License, Version 3.0</name>
      <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <contributors>
    <contributor>
      <name>Ruben Anders</name>
      <email>RAnders00@users.noreply.github.com</email>
      <url>https://github.com/RAnders00</url>
    </contributor>
  </contributors>
</project>
```

I looked at other projects on bintray and their pom files look similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the dependecy the traditional and simple way works fine:

```
compile 'randers.notenoughvocab.core:notenoughvocab-core:0.0.1'
```

It doesn't work when you specify [ext: 'jar'](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#ssub:artifact_dependencies), because that is used to download a single artifact. From the [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#ssub:artifact_dependencies):

> Artifact only notation
>
> As said above, if no module descriptor file can be found, Gradle by default downloads a jar with the name of the module. But sometimes, even if the repository contains module descriptors, you want to download only the artifact jar, without the dependencies. <sup>[[14](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#ftn.N15046)]</sup> And sometimes you want to download a zip from a repository, that does not have module descriptors. Gradle provides an artifact only notation for those use cases - simply prefix the extension that you want to be downloaded with '@' sign:
>
> Example 50.5. Artifact only notation
>
> build.gradle
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>    runtime "org.groovy:groovy:2.2.0@jar"
>    runtime group: 'org.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '2.2.0', ext: 'jar'
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I simply trusted the bintray quick copy: http://i.imgur.com/lPEStGm.png